# Text string from table add to select option with jquery

Tags: jquery, select, html-table

I have select with some option:

```html
<select class="mat">
    <option value="0">mat 1</option>
</select>
```

and table:

```html
<table id="mat-table">
    <tr>
        <td>option 1</td>
        <td>desc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>option 2</td>
        <td>desc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>option 3</td>
        <td>desc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want with jquery copy text 'option 1', 'option 2' from this table to select option  and get this:

```html
<select class="mat">
    <option value="0">option 1</option>
    <option value="1">option 2</option>
    <option value="2">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#mat-table td:first-child').each(function(i) {
    var $option = $('<option>', { value: i }).text(this.textContent);
    $('.mat').append($option);
});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ydz6myz/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mat').html('');
  var i = 0;
  $("#mat-table tr").each(function(){
    $('.mat').append($('<option>', {
      value: i,
      text: $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').html()
    }));
    i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mat">
  <option value="0">mat 1</option>
</select>
<table id="mat-table">
  <tr>
    <td>option 1</td>
    <td>desc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>option 2</td>
    <td>desc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>option 3</td>
    <td>desc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```